# Issue with SoftDelete and Plugin data handling in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, plugins, behavior, soft-delete

I am working on a CakePHP plugin. I have got a Log->LogColumn *hasMany* relationship and in the *belongsTo* relationship definition I have defined *countercache=>true*.

I have got [SoftDelete](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils) plugin activated [[link here]](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils). Now when I delete a record in LogColumn it wont update the *log_column_count* in Logs table.

The *countercache* calls however works alright in the App controllers/model calls of the application. However in case of Plugins think there is some problem.

I am attaching a screenshot from the SQL log.

Here is the LogColumn definition:

```
/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Log' => array(
            'className' => 'Log',
            'foreignKey' => 'log_id',
            'recursive'=>-1,
            'counterCache' => true,
        )
    );
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's something you should report in the projects issue tracker, as it's kind of a bug, at very least it's a missing feature. Same problem as in **https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/issues/55** I guess.

Comment: Right its' the same issue marked there. I had downloaded this Behavior months ago so I just needed to update with latest one. All fixed now.

Comment: Use updated [SoftDeleteBehavior][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148036/issue-with-softdelete-and-plugin-data-handling-in-cakephp